# Azure Data Factory read from Secondary onPremSQL

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have an ADF which pushes data from onPREM SQL to Azure SQL DW. Is there any property or configure which enable the ADF to read from the Secondary server instead of the primary

Comment: Doesn't the secondary have its own connection string / IP address?  You could look at ReadOnly Application Intent (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alwaysonpro/2013/08/02/connect-to-sql-server-using-application-intent-read-only/) but I'm not sure if that would work.

Comment: The secondary server indeed has it's own connection string and hostname. This is the correct way to divert to the secondary.

Comment: In a AlwaysOn scenario the connectionstring will have listener info. We cannot provide connection string of secondary as on failover the secondary will change to primary. there is a connection property of ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly which we generally pass but looking for a first hand information that if anybody has used this property while creating linkedservice for onPrem Sql